# Mongoose, get string record ID

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to setup a database using Mongoose for MongoDB, using nodejs. Currently when it performs findByID, it returns an object that I cannot seem to parse or turn into a string. I am trying to compare a supplied user id with the returned value as shown below.
How can I perform a FindBy.. function and have the result in a string format, so I can perform comparisons? Thanks

```
        globalTest = doc._id;
        
        //const foundUser = Auth.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(doc._id));
        const foundUser = Auth.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(globalTest));//.lean().exec();
    
        if(globalTest===foundUser){
            console.log('match');
        }else{
            console.log('no match');console.log(foundUser+' vs '+globalTest);              
        }
        console.log('BREAK: '+foundUser._id);//always undefined
```

And the console output:

```
Saving: 622f6ed69f5b04b4c82fce74 no match
auth.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("622f6ed69f5b04b4c82fce74") }) vs 622f6ed69f5b04b4c82fce74
BREAK: undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your console output `foundUser` is returning the query, you need to execute it in order the query to run and get the data.

I'm assuming you are using `async/await`

```
const foundUser = await Auth.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(globalTest)).lean().exec();

if (globalTest == foundUser._id) {
    console.log('match');
} else {
    console.log('no match')
}
```

Callback Version

```
Auth.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(globalTest)).lean().exec((err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

    if (globalTest == doc._id) {
        console.log('match');
    } else {
        console.log('no match')
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. However, I am unable to use async/await. Is there a callback method that will work?